# Using macro and array to lag a group of variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I tried to use macro and array to lag a bunch of variables by groups (id). my steps are:
1. lag all variables (groups not matter)
2. replace mis-lagged cells by `.`

but I found my code is buggy and appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the data:

```
data old;
  input id sale capx profit;
datalines;
1   11  111 1111
1   12  112 1112
1   13  113 1113
1   14  114 1114
1   15  115 1115
1   16  116 1116
1   17  117 1117
2   21  221 2221
2   22  222 2222
2   23  223 2223
3   31  331 3331
3   32  332 3332
3   33  333 3333
3   34  334 3334
4   41  441 4441
4   42  442 4442
4   43  443 4443
4   44  444 4444
4   45  445 4445
4   46  446 4446
;
run;
```

Code:

```
 data new;
 set old;
 run;

%macro lag_var(dataset, lag);
  proc sort data=&dataset;by id;
  data &dataset;
    set &dataset;
    by id;
    array vs(3) sale capx profit;
    %do j=1 %to 3;
            %do i=1 %to &lag;
            lag&j&i=lag&i(vs(&j));

            if first.id then 
            do;
            count=1;
            lag&j&i=.;
            end;
            count+1;
            if (not first.id and count<=&i) then
            do;
            lag&j&i=.;
            count+1;
            end;
            %end;
    %end;
  run;
%mend lag_var;

%lag_var(new,5)
```

Current output (wrong):
[image]

My expected results:
[image]

DomPazz's output:
[image]

Comment: Can you say something about what you're trying to achieve? It really looks like something you could/should be doing using a different approach. Clearly you want to summarise information on the last record of each by group - for what purpose? Some of it looks deterministic from your example data. And your approach doesn't look like it will survive ids with more observations.

Comment: Do you have access to PROC EXPAND? it is precisely useful for these type of scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason those later groups are keeping their value is that you are over incrementing `count`.

I think this does what you are looking for:

```
%macro lag_var(dataset, lag);
  proc sort data=&dataset;by id;
  data &dataset;
    set &dataset;
    by id;
    array vs(3) sale capx profit;
    %do j=1 %to 3;
            %do i=1 %to &lag;
            lag&j&i=lag&i(vs(&j));
            %end;
    %end;

    if first.id then do;
       count=0;
       %do j=1 %to 3;
          %do i=1 %to &lag;
             lag&j&i=.;
          %end;
       %end;
    end;

    count+1;

    %do j=1 %to 3;
       %do i=1 %to &lag;

          if (not first.id and count<=&i) then do;
               lag&j&i=.;
            /*count+1;*/
          end;
       %end;
    %end;
  run;
%mend lag_var;
```

EDIT: Changed the initialization of count from 1 to 0.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! But I think your solution is just a little bit from my expected results (please see the original post). For example the highlighted numbers should not existed. I am sorry this is my first SAS macro code...

Comment: The problem was in the starting value of count.  Changed that to 0 instead of 1.  It should remove those extra values coming across the by value boundary.